# Why does liquid change its shape when it's kept in a container and the container is accelerated?

Tags: fluid-dynamics

Pseudo force can't be the reason for it as it is not a real force. What is the reason?

Comment: You might be interested in [my answer to an earlier question](http://physics.stackexchange.com/a/210731/520) which related to pseudo-forces and liquids.

Answer (score 2):

*F=ma* (where F is force, m is mass, and a is acceleration)
the mass of the liquid is multiplied by the acceleration and you end up with a force that pushes the liquid against the wall of the container.

Another way of explaining it is by saying that the liquid has mass (I'm assuming it does) therefore it has inertia which means that the liquid wants to stay where it is)

From an inertial point of reference, there is no force pushing the water into the container wall, rather there is an applied force pushing the container into the liquid.

Comment: Thanks . Could you also please help me understand what is the pressure at the bottom wall of a cubical vessel (filled with fluid) of base surface area A?

Comment: _pressure=density of liquid x acceleration due to gravity x depth from surface_